# can my .NET framework 4 web application run on windows 8?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, windows-8

I've been developing a web application with an expected client machine OS of XP. I just found out that the customer upgraded their machines to Windows 8.

So my questions are:

- Can I still deploy my web application (.NET 4.0 and 2008 SQL Server express backend) on a Win 8 machine as expected?
- Are there any concerns for running my app on Win 8?

I haven't had time to even check out Windows 8 yet as I was not expecting this.

Comment: if its a web application client OS shouldn't really matter.. just browsers.. make sure your app works with latest browsers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, .NET 4.0 application can work without any problems on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2008/2012.

Comment: No concerns on deployment on those boxes as they will host their own site?

Comment: Windows XP uses IIS 5.5 whereas Windows 8 Enterprise uses IIS 8. So there might be different ways to configure the web server.